# php Url Get array issue

Tags: php, mysql, url, foreach, get

```
   <select multiple name="type[]" >
   <option  value="" >Изберете тип</option>
   <?php 
          $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','seacapit_webhelper');
 mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$query4 = "SELECT distinct search_txt3 FROM products WHERE search_txt3 <> '' 
order by search_txt3 ";
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4);
while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)){
$tipove = trim ($row4['search_txt3']);

echo "<option>".$tipove."</option> "; } 
?>

</select>
//This works
if(!empty($_POST['type'])) {
  foreach($_POST['type'] as $something)
  { 
    $this[] = "search_txt3 LIKE '%".$something."%'";
  }
  $sql .= " AND ".implode(" OR ", $this);
 }

//This doesn't
if(!empty($_GET['type'])) {
  foreach($_GET['type'] as $something)
  { 
    $this[] = "search_txt3 LIKE '%".$something."%'";
  }
  $sql .= " AND ".implode(" OR ", $this);
}
```

the error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Why does $_GET not read the array and instead it reads it as it is actually the word array ? Thank you guys in advance

Comment: is `$_POST['type']` an array? of values?

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET`?

Comment: Its a select box with multiple='mulitple' options and for to the first results I use POST, but on the second page when I try using GET is where I dont succeed

Comment: OK, well show us your form and your processing scripts (if different).

Comment: I edited it * Sorry

Comment: That's just the select option. Show us your form and the processing script.

Comment: I dont think you need the whole form, however if this is what your asking 'action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>' the form handles it on the same page and the the link for the next page "<a class='navibtn' href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$prev_page&txtKeyword=$strKeyword&type=$type"

Comment: Without all Information it is very difficult to help!

Comment: You should avoid using **this** as a **variable name** since **$this** is a pseudo-variable in an object context.

Answer (score 0):

Assign  $_GET['type'] to $type.

```
if(!empty($_GET['type'])){
$type[] =$_GET['type'];
foreach($type as $neshto)
{ 
$this[] = "search_txt3 LIKE '%".$something."%'";
}
$sql .= " AND ".implode(" OR ", $this);
}
```

Comment: its assigned, doesnt do anything different

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is in the **form** tag itself. I am guessing, because the complete form is not shown in the code example. So please check that the form you are using to submit the **select** has a **method="GET"** or it does not have a **method** attribute at all *("GET" this is default method for forms)*